# how to allow only specific users to add/delete items from a list in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm working on requirement, where we have a list with categories we want to maintain list own our own. we want others to restrict from add/ delete/modify, only we want to do that.
Is it possible to do it in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can stop inheriting permissions from the site in the list and assign unique permissions to the users.

Go to List sttings > Permissions for this list.

[image]

Click Stop Inheriting Permissions in the ribbon > Slect all existing groups and users > Remove User Permissions > Grant full control Permissions to specific users and grant read permission to other users.